# How do I make a code that will make Java code/file to an .exe file

Tags: java

I have a weird internet privacy freak out downloading something so I want to write a code that will make java into .exe. I am wondering if I need to make it an .exe file to run or should I make it in assembly. If I make it in raw code do I use assembly or binary or something else.